# How to connect Azure SQL database to ASP.NET website hosted on a different server

Tags: sql, azure, connection, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have created Sql database from Azure using my subscription. I copied the connection string supplied with my credentials correctly into my code and it work in visual studio but when I deployed to my hosting server for my website it displays connection error. I have set IP range to accept all IP yet not working.

Comment: Most likely the Application Pool user on your server is not allowed to access network resources. You can easily confirm this by creating another Application Pool with your own user and try running your website on this Application Pool

Answer (score 0):

By default, (when you create a new DB), Azure blocks ALL traffic to your database. In order to allow traffic to your database either you need to whitelist all the IP address or the best suggestion in your case is to enable '**Allow access to Azure Services**' on the SQL Server settings. Find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureedu/what-should-i-know-when-setting-up-my-azure-sql-database-paas#firewall)

Comment: OP stated they *"have set IP range to accept all IP"* so I#d expect they are already aware of this.